# Получение списка значений характеристик

Tags: moysklad-json-api

коллеги.
Не могу понять, если возможность в API получить список значений характеристик модификаций.
Сами характеристики можно получить через */entity/variant/metadata*, но в ответе не содержатся значения.
Можно запросить данные по конкретной характеристике */entity/variant/metadata/characteristics/{id}*, но там значений тоже нет.

Вместе с тем, в пользовательском интерфейсе в фильтре товаров присутствуют выпадающие списки значений характеристик.

Answer (score 0):

Значение характеристик для модификации можно получить из запроса `curl -X GET \
  https://online-18.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.2/entity/variant/{variant_id} \
  -H 'Authorization: Basic YOUR_LOGIN_PASS' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: POSTMAN_TOKEN' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache'`

поле "characteristics" значение поля "value". Отдельного запроса на получение значения характеристики для конкретной модификации нет.

Comment: Это значения характеристик для конкретной модификации, а меня интересует список всех значений характеристики, которые есть в системе.